# MySQL, populate column values based on another column while converting dash-separated uppercase to some user friendly words

Tags: mysql, regex

Here is **the situation**:

- there is a table with 2 columns, **code** and **name**,
- name columns are all empty,
- code columns are all upper case dash separated i.e. **PUBLIC-CLASS**, **STATIC-PUBLIC-CLASS**,
- I need a query to update names with codes value converted to user friendly format which is fiIi can use regex like pattern to distinguish such cases

```
UPDATE tableName
SET 
    name = CONCAT(
        UPPER(SUBSTR(REPLACE(code, '-', ' '), 1, 1)),
        LCASE(SUBSTR(REPLACE(code, '-', ' '), 2))
    )
WHERE
    name = '';
```

Any help is appreciated :)

---

Here is a before :

```
| code                | name                |
+=====================+=====================+
| PUBLIC-CLASS        |                     |
| PRIVATE-CLASS       | Already has a name  |
| STATIC-PUBLIC-CLASS |                     |
| PHP-PUBLIC-LASS     |                     |
| HTTP-REQUEST        |                     |
```

and after:

```
| code                | name                |
+=====================+=====================+
| PUBLIC-CLASS        | Public class        |
| PRIVATE-CLASS       | Already has a name  |
| STATIC-PUBLIC-CLASS | Static public class |
| PHP-PUBLIC-LASS     | PHP Public class    |
| HTTP-REQUEST        | HTTP Request        |
```

example as per  @Abecee request :)

Comment: Could you, please, provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Sure thing @Abecee, I'm going to update the question in a sec :)

Comment: (i) Are you going to provide a list of words, which should always be *all capitals*? (ii) Could *all capitals* words be in the middle of the sequence? How should, e.g., "PUBLIC-HTTP-CLASS" look after processing?

Comment: (i) Yes, It is possible to arrange a list of all abbreviations which we want them all capital. (ii) No, they are always in the beginning  of the code [at least for now :) ], thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the data shown so far, you could try along:

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET name = CASE
      FIELD(SUBSTR(code, 1, INSTR(code, '-') - 1), 'HTTP', 'PHP')
      WHEN 0 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTR(code, 1, 1),
                         LCASE(SUBSTR(REPLACE(code, '-', ' '), 2))
                        )
      ELSE CONCAT(SUBSTR(code, 1, INSTR(code, '-') - 1),
                  ' ',
                  SUBSTR(SUBSTR(code, INSTR(code, '-') + 1), 1, 1),
                  LCASE(SUBSTR(REPLACE(SUBSTR(code, INSTR(code, '-') + 1), '-', ' '), 2))
                 )
      END
WHERE name IS NULL
;
```

There is no need for a regex to separate the cases. Just keep adding expressions to preserve (at the beginning of your strings) to the list in `FIELD(SUBSTR(code, 1, INSTR(code, '-') - 1), 'HTTP', 'PHP')`. (This could sure be handled via a table in the database, if wanted/needed.)
And changes to strings are not supported by MySQL regex up until now anyway.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fabb7/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution (but not so elegant) will be:

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET 
    name = IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '-', 1) IN ('PHP' , 'HTTP'),
        CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '-', 1)),
                LCASE(SUBSTR(REPLACE(code, '-', ' '),
                            CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '-', 1)) + 1))),
        CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(REPLACE(code, '-', ' '), 1, 1)),
                LCASE(SUBSTR(REPLACE(code, '-', ' '), 2))))
WHERE
    name IS NULL;
```

Comment: Actually in my case using the `IF` statement is enough and we can leave the `CASE` clause for situations with more conditions. Thanks @m.cekiera